# Can I create unlimited marks with vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to be able to set additional marks to the already existing *single lettered marks*. Thus, I could solve two problemes I am currently facing:

1. the marks are set in a script and I don't want to destroy marks that were already set by the user of the script
2. I could set an unlimited number of marks so that I don't have to count them (I'd name them something like `"script_mrk_" . s:mark_count`).

So, if expressed as function calls, I am probably looking for something

```
setPrivateMark(l:mark_name, l:line, l:pos)
```

and

```
let line_pos = getPrivateMark(l:mark_name)
```

Of course, the solution should be resistant to changes to the buffer above the mark after setting it with `setPrivateMark` and before `getPrivateMark(...)`.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: You said the marks are set in a script; for what purpose? As a rule of thumb, if your script is setting marks, there's probably a better approach.

Comment: Currently, the marks come in pairs. One mark starts and the other marks ends a "special" sections in the code that I want to tread differently when various functions are called.

Comment: Have you considered accomplishing this using a custom syntax instead? It sounds like it might be perfect for the job, depending on how these sections of code are defined.

Comment: `.... depending on how these sections of code are defined.` and herein lies the problem: the sections are not somehow syntactically (or with a regular expression) defined. This is why I want/need the marks.

Comment: How are they defined, exactly? It may still be possible to avoid using marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim only updates the position of its built-in marks on changes; if you need that functionality, you have to use those, and are limited to the number of existing marks.

There's no way around this; for simple user edits, you could hook into the `CursorMovedI` event and adapt your recorded positions, but there's no way to hook Ex commands like `:append`.

If you need a couple of marks for a plugin, it's good practice to allow the user to configure the marks used by the script (e.g. via a `g:MyPlugin_UseMarks` variable); hardly anyone uses all the marks all the time, but different people have different preferences.

Comment: +1 no matter what kind of questions, you can always give insightful answers!

Answer (score 0):

unlimited mark I don't know, but you can create a dictionary type, key is your "mark" name, value is the position of cursor.

position could be get and set by

```
getpos() and setpos()
```

or you want the actual codes?

Comment: Well, if the user inserts or deletes line above the coordinates evaluated with `getpos()`, the coordinates wouldn't be accurate anymore

Comment: it is true... so you need the **real** mark, not the mark only used in your script..

Comment: Yes. The user calls a functionality in the script which sets or modifies the private marks, the script returns, the users edits the buffer (and the private marks flow with the changed text) and *then* the user calls the script again which is when the script needs the marks previously set.